# TexShop line number magnification

Tags: mac, editors, texshop, magnification

Does anyone know how to change the size of the line number font in the grey left-hand column?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to change this.

Comment: If TeXShop is like TeXStudio then changing the document font size will also change the size of the line number font.

Comment: But I'm sure the authors would know how to do this. ;-)

Comment: No, increasing the source font size/magnification doesn't change the size of the line numbers. I know of no way to do this in TeXShop.

Comment: If you are using a recent version of TeXShop you might be able to make the numbers easier to see by reducing the transparency (alpha) of the Source window in the Themes tab of TeXShop->Preferences. No guarantees.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments on my question. It would be great if it could be considered as an item for a future upgrade (as Tex users get older!).

Comment: I don't know if the TeXshop maintainer frequent this site, to ensure that your feature request is seen it would likely be better to use the contact link in the top right of https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/